# Brownian motion and geometric series convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm confused with the property of Brownian motion that it is of infinite variation.
Consider the sequence
$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} a^{t-i} (B_{i+1} - B_i)$$
where $a \in [0,1)$ and $B_t$ is Brownian motion.

Would this sequence converge for $t \rightarrow \infty$ like the geometric series? Or does it not converge due to infinite variation of Brownian motion?

Comment: So you are asking about the exponential moving average (EMA) of a sequence of independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) normal variables. No, there will be no convergence.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the infinite variation of Brownian motion.  That usually refers to the fact that if we look at partitions $0 = t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_N = T$ of the interval $[0,T]$, then $\sum_{i=1}^N |B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i}| \rightarrow \infty$ as the partition gets finer.  That is, the infinite variation property is about adding up the increments over a fixed period of time, rather than over an infinite time frame.

Answer (score 2):

The variables $$S_m= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a^{m-i} (B_{i+1} - B_i)$$ converge in distribution to the law of
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a^j Z_j \,,$$
where $Z_j$ are i.i.d. standard normal variables.

The variables $ S_m$
do not converge a.s. because
$E[S_m S_{m+k}] \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ for each $m$.

Comment: Are you really sure? The variance of a single sum is $\frac{a^2}{1-a^2}(1-a^{2t})$, so the sum over the variances of the first $N$ sums behaves like $\frac{a^2}{1-a^2}(N-\frac{a^2}{1-a^2}(1-a^{2N}))$ which certainly diverges.

Comment: I misread the coefficients.  The sum does not converge pointwise, only in distribution. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I have a question about the absolute value of the increments. If we do not consider the absolute value of the increments, would the sum then converge? The sequence $\sum_{i=0}^t B(i+1)-B(i)$ should converge due to telescopic sum to $B_t-B_0$, but when $t$ goes to infinity then it does not converge, am I right?